# Running header with first three letters

Tags: adobe-indesign

I need to make a dictionary-style three letter running header on each page.  How can I use only first three letters, not the whole word?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out, this is quite easy to do
with nested style of the paragraph style (linked with variable).
Just set "3" and "letters" in the dropdown menu.

[image: Paragraph Style Options]